# Nameserver Update and Gmail Account

Tags: gmail, web-hosting, nameserver

I have a domain name with GoDaddy and I have my domain name setup with Google to receive email using that domain name (name@mydomain.com). Yesterday I bought a WinHost account and had to update the nameserver information. Will changing the nameserver information to Winhost's nameserver information interrupt my Google apps (specifically Blogger and Gmail)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES, unless you also copy all your current DNS records to the new DNS server too. You should do that before you move your name servers, although some control panels don't allow that until they are officially named as your name server. In that case, you make the changes ASAP although mail flow will be delayed while they propagate.

Why don't you just add any new records you need within your Google DNS manager? You do not have to move your DNS to Winhost. Post back with what new records you need for Winhost, and I can tell you how to do them.

Comment: I followed the instructions on this page: http://support.winhost.com/KB/a512/name-server-update-information-domains-registered-with.aspx. After about an hour my site has now moved to Winhost (lewisrb.com). So since that's all I did, my gmail account will break now?

Comment: Yep you're right. I just tested it and it failed. Email coming...

Comment: Yes, your e-mail is probably not working unless the DNS is cached, and that will age out and stop working totally. You need to go into Godaddy and determine every DNS record you have there, and copy them to your new name servers.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it is now too late, what you should of done if kept your **DNS Records** in place and just forwarded your site to the proper **IP Address**. For example:

```
@            A            123.456.789.012
www          CNAME        mydomain.com
```

Your host should give you the proper IP to forward the traffic to. Ask them nicely. If that doesn't work, start looking for a new host.